# friendly_id generate slug with ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I am trying to use the friendly_id gem to generate a slug in the format of "#{id}-#{title}"

It looks like friendly_id uses before_save, and won't have access to the ID attribute.

Is there a work around for this ?

```
# Permalinks
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :id_and_title, :use => :slugged

def id_and_title
  "#{id} #{title}"
end
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue with `friendly_id`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of using friendly_id for this, you could override `to_param` in your model, to include the title

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param
    "#{id} #{title}".parameterize
  end
end
```

This should have the effect you're after without having to use friendly_id.

Comment: Ye I ended up going with this approach. You just lose the slug history  with this approach.   Thanks

Comment: This answer this very specific question... if you decide to use the ID at the end, it won't work, like `#{title} #{id}.parameterize`